# Where is Github tf - slim pre-trained model zoo? The page returns 404

Tags: github, tensorflow, deep-learning, tf-slim

A well known place to download many pretrained model weights for tensorflow slim is this page https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim. This page is also referenced by lots of links(now all invalid). I remember a couple of days ago I visited this page and all is fine, but now it simply stops working(github returns 404). Can anybody kindly inform me if it is moved to some other place, or completely deleted. Or, can somebody suggest me a place to download classical CNNs pretrained weights for tensorflow or tf-slim. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it got moved last week, see this -- https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/cOmsaKtfNZU

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov Thank you very much. It solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tf.slim` code has been moved to https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim.